# Q. Is there a formal definition of the word "rigorous"?

Tags: definition, foundations, formal-proofs

I would like to ask if there is a formal definition of the word **"rigorous"**. I think I have a grasp of the concept of "formal stuffs" but I feel like the word "rigorous" is NOT objective enough.

eg. When reading combinatoric proofs, I always have difficulty in understanding the logic behind them as they often lie on the obscure boundary between logic and common sense.

Comment: Can you explain your example? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: The concept evolved during history of mathematics; see G.Schubring, [Conflicts Between Generalization, Rigor, and Intuition (2005)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Conflicts_Between_Generalization_Rigor_a/rMWe3okqPOcC)

Comment: For example, here is a solution to "the number of 1-1 functions there are from {1, 2, 3, 4} to itself?":

" If the function is 1-1 then we have 4 possible choices for f(1) but, once that
choice is made, only 3 possibilities for f(2) and so on. Hence the number of 1-1 functions is 4 × 3 × 2 × 1 = 4! = 24. "

Although it makes sense, but how do we know if we have missed sth? eg double-counting etc.

I would say my question is about mathematical solutions or proofs in general instead of a specific branch. Combinatorics is just an example I could think of.

Comment: You might be thinking of combinatorics proofs as being weirdly non-rigorous because the "obviously rigorous" phrasing is verbose and unwieldy. I imagine most of the combinatorics proofs you have in mind here can be mechanically transformed into "obviously rigorous" proofs if you express them as facts about the cardinalities of sets. For example, "noting that some quantity is equal to some other quantity because they're two ways of counting the same thing" is really an equality of the two quantities going via the cardinality of that set.

Comment: No there is no rgorous definition of the word rigorous. There is also no definition of the word definition.

Comment: @GHG Can you please clarify what you are asking? In your post, it sounds like you want a precise definition of rigor in a mathematical context but your example above suggests that you are really asking how you know your proof is correct.

Comment: @John Douma Yes, I was trying to find a precise definition in terms of formal language of the word "rigorous", this is because I think that formal proofs are easier to be verified than the combinatoric examples I gave.

Answer (score 2):

"Rigorous," in contrast with "formal," is a fuzzy term. A formalist might say that an argument should be thought of as rigorous insofar as it would be straightforward to turn it into a formal (e.g. LEAN-checkable) proof, but broadly speaking an argument is rigorous iff it "meets the standards" of the mathematical community. Those standards might change, of course, and what is considered rigorous one day might not be considered rigorous the next; however, since (for better or worse) most mathematical arguments are not machine-checkable, this subjective distinction is important enough to deserve a name.